# how to read in input the second column of a text file as the values of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a lot of text files with two columns , for example :

```
    1998-08  56
    1998-09  78
    1998-10  12
    1998-11  76
```

and I have a MATLAB code , which I want to run it with octave. This code generates a random matrix (c) and then calculates Poisson inverse, now instead of a random matrix I want to tell it get the second column of the text file as values of c . 
and then once I have calculated I want to plot the results in a graph with dates on the first columns as values of x axis.
my question is naive but I'm very very new to octave and I spent last day searching a documentation but I found nothing useful.

```
     clc
     clear all
     #here I need to read in input the second columns of each file 
     C =     [8,9,3,6,4,1,5,8,3,5,8,10,5,3,1,5,11,3,6,5,8,5,1,3,5,3,3,7,0,2,6,7,1,8,3,5,2,6,3,5,3,8,2,5,2,7,4,4,5,50,7,5,3,3,8,2,7,7,3,6,4,4,2,4,5,1,5,14,2,6,1,4,7,3,4,6,1,3,4,4,5,1,5,4,4,6,6,2,0,4,8,9,4,5,10,3,4,2,3,6,6,8,5,5,8,3,8,4,5,4,1,4,6,5,2,5,5,7,5,1,5,4,5,3,5,11,8,6,6,0,6,4,6,5,6,4,6,4,11,4,6,5,4,4,4,2,4,7,4,40,7,7,3,1,6,7,7,4,10,5,5,4,8,5,4,5,2,7,8,6,7,6,4,3,3,3,4,6,1,7,2,6,5,7,3,6,3,6,2,3,4,7,2,4,3,6,4,7,9,5,6,2,4,4,7,4,6,3,5,3,3,5,4,8,5,3,6,4,8,6,3,8,2,7,5,3,3,8,8,4,4,8,5,7,4,4,3,6,8,4,3,4,3,9,4,3,10,4,4,5];
    C = C';

    N = length(C);
    H = 6;
    w = [1:H H+1 H:-1:1]';

    Lambda_Tilde = NaN * zeros(N, 1);
    L_Tilde = NaN * zeros(N, 1);
    U_Tilde = NaN * zeros(N, 1);
    for t = (H+1):(N-H-1)
       Lambda_Tilde(t) = sum(w .* C(t-H:t+H)) / sum(w);
       L_Tilde(t) = poissinv(0.005, Lambda_Tilde(t));
       U_Tilde(t) = poissinv(0.995, Lambda_Tilde(t));
    end

    clf
    plot(1:N, C, 'bo-');
    hold on
    plot(1:N, L_Tilde, 'r-.');
    plot(1:N, U_Tilde, 'r-.');
```

Comment: Your code is not relevant for this question, what have you tried to [import your data](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/data-import-and-export.html)? There is really a lot of good documentation out there, so "found nothing useful" is hard to believe. Especially `csvread` and `importdata` could be interesting for you. Or tell us what didn't work with your attempts.

Comment: @thewaywalk that's exactly the point . this is my code on a random matrix , I've figured out how my formula works but I can not import my data to make it work on mine not on a random matrix! now i check the import data link! thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import and Export of data is really [**well documented**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html), so "found **nothing** useful" is hard to believe. Especially [**`importdata`**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) could be interesting for you.

```
data = importdata('Data.txt');
C = data.data.';
```

returns:

```
C =

    56    78    12    76
```

---

off-topic:

`NaN * zeros(N, 1)` is the same as `NaN(N, 1)`

Comment: I needed some simple tutorial for a very new beginner on this stuff. thank you so much :-)